# Cultural before-and-afters

Tags: knowledge, wordplay

Each answer to a clue will consist of the titles of two works or series put together, where the last word of the first title matches the first word of the second title.

Note that the word match does not have to be exact; for example, the last word of the first title might be a plural version of a singular first word of the second title.  Also, you might have to remove an initial article from the second title to get the match.

Example: Collaboration of the Eagles with the Mamas and the Papas.  A: Hotel California Dreamin'.

1. Fictional futuristic reality show featuring conscript combat, along with dragons and frequent main character deaths.
2. Theme song to a new Rocky movie featuring video editing to include a '40s movie star.
3. Late '80s/early '90s sitcom dad goes to Washington.
4. James Bond engages in sword fights with numerous ninjas on the Eiffel Tower.
5. A pirate crew discovers a mad scientist creating hybrid animals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I know some of the answers.

1

> Hunger Game(s) of Thrones

4

> A View to Kill Bill

5

> Treasure Island of Dr. Moreau

Comment: 1 is "futuristic" - it's [rot13](https://rot13.com/)(Raqre'f Tnzr bs Guebarf).

Comment: @Deusovi But IMO the answer by Octopus does fit "futuristic" as well, just maybe not nearly as much.  It also fits the "reality show" part which your answer does not.

Comment: Correct on #1, 4, 5

Answer (score 6):

For 2, what about

> Bette Davis Eye(s) of the Tiger ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 5):

I think 3 might be

> Full House of Cards

Comment: Correct answer on #3